# Which one 'wait' I can use for waiting before next action in Selenium with C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, nuget, xunit

I am trying to find and implement effective and correct 'wait' in my tests in **selenium** with **C#**. I've used **xunit**, and **xunit.runner** for run my tests.

I'd tried use Page Object Model before I ran tests. But I still have problem with working 'wait'. I want do something after (for example) 5 seconds.
It's my test case:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xunit;

namespace AutomationTest
{
    public class TestCase
    {

        [Fact]
        public void FormTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form");
            FormsPage formsPage = PageFactory.InitElements<FormsPage>(driver);
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            **WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8));

            string name = "Jurek";
            string lastName = "Jarecki";
            string number = "1234567890";
            //Act
            formsPage.PressFirstName(name);
            formsPage.ChooseGender();
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelected(By.XPath("//label[contains(text(),'Female')]")));
           
            formsPage.MobileNumber(number);

            js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,950);");
            formsPage.SbtClick();
            // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,0);");
            formsPage.PressLastName(lastName);
            // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
            js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,950);");
            formsPage.SbtClick();

            //Assert
            formsPage.AssertIsCorrectNumber(number);
            driver.Dispose();
        } 
      }
    }
```

I want find a method which will wait for 5 seconds after running `formsPage.ChooseGender();`

This is `FormPage` class:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace AutoTest03.Page_Object
{
   public class FormsPage
    {
        private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

        public FormsPage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this._driver = driver;
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "firstName")]
        private IWebElement firstName;

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "lastName")]
        private IWebElement lastName;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//label[contains(text(),'Female')]")]
        private IWebElement female;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@id='userNumber']")]
        private IWebElement mobileNumber;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@id='state']//div[contains(@class,'css-1hwfws3')]")]
        private IWebElement stateAndCity;

        [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "css-1uccc91-singleValue")]
        private IWebElement haryana;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//button[@id='submit']")]
        private IWebElement submitButton;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//td[contains(text(),'Jacek Opoczny')]")]
        private IWebElement fullNameTextArea;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//td[contains(text(),'1234567890')]")]
        private IWebElement exampleNumber;

        #region Methods
        public FormsPage PressFirstName(string firName)
        {

            firstName.SendKeys(firName.ToString());
            return this;
        }
        
        public FormsPage PressLastName(string lasName)
        {
            lastName.SendKeys(lasName.ToString());
            return this;

        }
        public FormsPage ChooseGender()
        {
            female.Click();
            return this;

        }
        public FormsPage MobileNumber(string number)
        {
            mobileNumber.SendKeys(number);
            return this;
        }
        public FormsPage StateAndCity()
        {
            stateAndCity.Click();
           
            haryana.Click();
            return this;
        }
        public FormsPage SbtClick()
        {
            submitButton.Click();        

        return this;
        }
        #endregion

        public void AssertIsCorrectNumber(string correctNumber)
        {
            var excpectedNumber = exampleNumber.Text;
            Assert.Equal(excpectedNumber, correctNumber);
        }
        public void AssertIsCorrectName(string name, string last)
        {
            var fullName = fullNameTextArea;
            Assert.Equal(name + " " + last, fullName.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that `Thread.Sleep();` is absolutely not recommended.

Comment: if you want to wait for 5 seconds, sleep is exactly what you want... but maybe you don't need to wait that long.   Selenium includes explicit and implicit waits which will wait only as long as is needed.  (And yes, they do use sleep to poll at 1/2 second intervals)

Answer (score 1):

Try Either of the `Explicit` Wait

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//label[contains(text(),'Female')]")));
```

OR

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//label[contains(text(),'Female')]")));
```